# C# console application authentication session

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cli2, az

How could someone implement the `az login` (Azure CLI) experience in a C# Console application?

In that case, a browser window is opened, the user authenticates and after that he can access the private resources.
My guess is that the authentication token is stored somewhere, but where? Session variable, file..?

**Update**

I found out that there is a folder `~/.azure` storing the relevant information. So the question is more on the first part (starting a browser and getting the resulting token).

Comment: Is `az` meant to be `azure`?  If so use the latter and flag the former as a synonym

Answer (score 0):

> How could someone implement the az login (Azure CLI) experience in a C# Console application?

1.Starting a browser with `Process.Start(@"http://url");`. After user enter his credential, you will get the authorization code. Copy it.

2.Get an authorization code.

3.Get access token with following code:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ContentType", "application/json");
    var requestURl = new Uri($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/v2.0/token");
    string body = "{\"client_id\": \"3c35ed0b-a441-4c57-9d1c-3a3b0392d9c3\",\"code\":\"the_code_you_copy_in_the_second_step\",\"redirect_uri\": \"https://localhost\",\"grant_type\": \"authorization_code\",\"client_secret\": \"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx\",\"scope\": \"user.read\"}";
    var stringContent = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var response = client.PostAsync(requestURl, stringContent).Result;
}
```

4.The result:[image]

For more detials about how to get `authorization code` and `access token` you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow).

Comment: Thank you @Joey, but I'm expecting that the entire operation is automated in the CLI. How can I get the value from step 1?

Comment: If you want to get the access token directly after enter user credential, you could use  [implicit grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow).